# Convertir un byte[] a un tipo de objeto propio NO serializable, Java

Tags: java, byte

Necesito convertir un array de byte a un objeto propio que no implementa la interfaz Serializable pero que si tiene atributos serializables, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?. Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma pero me da error porque pide que la clase Documento implemente serializable.

```
        byte[] documentoFirmado = null;
        
        ByteArrayInputStream is = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = null;
        Documento doc= null;
        
        documentoFirmado = obtenerDocumentoFirmado(docex);
        
        //pasar de byte[] a tipo Documento
                
        try {
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(documentoFirmado);
            objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            doc = (Documento) objectinputstream.readObject();
            objectinputstream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            LOG.error(ioexception.getMessage());
            doc =  null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundexception) {
            LOG.error(classnotfoundexception.getMessage());
        }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si no es serializable, no se ha podido serializar (convertir a un array de bytes), ¿Qué es lo que hay en ese array, entonces?

Comment: La variable 'documentoFirmado' contiene un array de bytes que es lo que retorna el método al que llama ('obtenerDocumentoFirmado').